# GWT error at runtime: ....style_0 is null

Tags: gwt

My code works fine in IE 8, but on firefox 3.5, the javascript fails to load. I used firebug to figure out why, and the error I get is (GWT detailed mode)

My suspicion is that some style is not defined in the CSS, but I have not been able to find anything.

thanks
Siddharth

com_google_gwt_dom_client_DOMImplMozilla_$getBodyOffsetLeft__Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_DOMImplMozilla_2Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_Document_2_style_0 is null

The stacktrace reveals:
com_google_gwt_dom_client_Document_$getBodyOffsetLeft__Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_Document_2(Document qbsearch.html)FC971AE8...ache.html (line 599)
com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_PopupPanel_$setPopupPosition__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_PopupPanel_2II(, Object name=left value=0, Object name=top value=0)FC971AE8...ache.html (line 5178)
com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_DialogBox_$DialogBox__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_DialogBox_2()FC971AE8...ache.html (line 5372)
com_intuit_search_client_Qbsearch2_$Qbsearch2__Lcom_intuit_search_client_Qbsearch2_2(com.intuit.search.client.Qbsearch2@2)FC971AE8...ache.html (line 8298)
init()FC971AE8...ache.html (line 11000)

(URL removed...)

maybeStartModule()qsearch...ocache.js (line 39)
anonymous()qsearch...ocache.js (line 215)
FC971AE816AD9EEF5906AB56B24F3639.cache.html()FC971AE8...ache.html (line 11023)
[Break on this error] return com_google_gwt_dom_client_DOMIm...nt_Document_2_style_0.borderLeftWidth);\n

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there are certain widgets you cannot use if you are using a hidden iframe, including HorizontalSplitPanel and DialogBox. Removing these from my startup fixed the problem